# How to get value of the slider, when touchend or mouseup events are used?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchend', function(){
// how can I get slider's value here?
});

$('.ui-slider-handle').live('mouseup', function(){
// and here?
});
```

I don't want to use `.change` since it is called even when sliders are moving.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the event `stop`
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop

Comment: How to use that? `$( ".ui-slider-handle" ).bind( "slidestop", function(event, ui) {` doesn't catch that.

Comment: You bind to the slider, not the handle. It would be better to use this event instead of using live mouseup and touchend

Comment: `$('#slider1').bind('slidestop', function(event, ui) {` doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's fairly simple to get the current value of a slider:

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').live('mouseup', function() {
  var value = $(this).closest('.ui-slider').slider('value');
});
```

You'll have to experiment with this though, because I've found that often this is not the most-up-to-date value (it's usually one click less than the actual final value).

What you REALLY want to do is use the slidestop event built-in to the slider widget, but of course right now it is not supporting touchend for some reason. (Along with a few other issues on touch devices.)

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work. I see the following error in console: `uncaught exception: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value'`.

Comment: Just so we're on the same page -- at some point during initialization, you are calling $('#mydiv').slider(), right? You aren't inserting divs with class "ui-slider-handle" into your actual HTML?

Comment: I didn't call `slider()` before, but I've added `'$('#slider1').slider();` just now - it didn't help. And, I don't have divs with class `ui-slider-handle`.